# Python: Import text from HTML or text document into Word

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-docx, text-processing

I've been looking at some of the documentation, but all of the work I've seen around docx is primarily directed towards working *with* text already in a word document. What I'd like to know, is is there a simple way to take text either from HTML or a Text document, and import that into a word document, and to do that wholesale? with all of the text in the HTML/Text document? It doesn't seem to like the string, it's too long.

My understanding of the documentation, is that you have to work with text on a paragraph by paragraph basis. The task that I'd like to do is relatively simple - however it's beyond my python skills. I'd like to set up the margins on the word document, and then import the text into the word document so that it adheres to the margins that I previously specified.

Does anyone have any-thoughts? None of the previous posts have been very helpful that I have found.

```
import textwrap
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches


class DocumentWrapper(textwrap.TextWrapper):

    def wrap(self, text):
        split_text = text.split('\n\n')
        lines = [line for para in split_text for line in textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap(self, para)]
        return lines

page = requests.get("http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/prior.mb.txt")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")

#we are going to pull in the text wrap extension that we have added.
#The typical width that we want tow
text_wrap_extension = DocumentWrapper(width=82,initial_indent="",fix_sentence_endings=True)
new_string = text_wrap_extension.fill(page.text)

final_document = "Prior_Analytics.txt"

with open(final_document, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(new_string)

document = Document(final_document)


### Specified margin specifications
sections = document.sections
for section in sections:
    section.top_margin = (Inches(1.00))
    section.bottom_margin = (Inches(1.00))
    section.right_margin = (Inches(1.00))
    section.left_margin = (Inches(1.00))

document.save(final_document)
```

The error that I get thrown is below:

```
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'Prior_Analytics.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
document = Document()
sections = document.sections
for section in sections:
    section.top_margin = Inches(2)
    section.bottom_margin = Inches(2)
    section.left_margin = Inches(2)
    section.right_margin = Inches(2)
document.add_paragraph(###Add your text here. Add Paragraph Accepts text of whatever size.###)
document.save()#name of document goes here, as a string.
```

Comment: Also note, once you open up the word document, it doesn't look like the word document actually reflects that it has the dimensions in it that you've set up. They are none-the-less there.

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means there is no `.docx` file at the location you specified.. So you can modify your code to create the file it it doesnt exist.

```
final_document = "Prior_Analytics.txt"

with open(final_document, "w+") as f:
    f.writelines(new_string)
```

You are providing a relative path. How do you know what Python's current working directory is? That's where the relative path you give will start from.

A couple lines of code like this will tell you:

```
import os
print(os.path.realpath('./'))
```

Note that:

> `docx` is used to open `.docx` files

Comment: I'm not sure how to import the text into a word document though, with the specified margins. which is what i'm looking to do.

Comment: Try here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-working-with-docx-module/

Comment: I was really hoping to get away with creating a word document, managing the margins in the way that we discussed, and then pouring the code pouring the text into the document after the margins had been managed. This does not appear to be possible based on what you sent me. It looks like I'll have to manage the text on a paragraph by paragraph basis, or line by line basis. Can you confirm if that is your understanding as well?

Comment: I guess I use the HTML and create an object for each line, and iterate over the lines with the line manage and pour it in that way. How do I know the script know to start over with a new paragraph though? That's what I'm struggling with so much, and the headers/titles etc....

Comment: I see. Let me check if I can helpy uo in that

Comment: You need something else from me? I haven't been able to find anything.